# I am getting an undesired output on the execution of function for outliers detection. the code as follows

Tags: python, numpy

````
  ```
  outliers = []
   ` def detect_outliers(data): `
        threshold=3
  `      mean = np.mean(data) `
  `      std = np.std(data)  `
   `     for i in data:    `
     `       z_score = (i-mean)/std `
       `     if np.abs(z_score) > threshold: `
          `      outliers.append(i)  `
        return outliers 

```detect_outliers(B5)  ```
output : [999.0, 999.0, 999.0, 999.0, 999.0, 999.0, 999.0, 999.0]
````

The column B5 has 6 outliers and I am getting 8 as u can see above.
the function doesn't give desired number of outliers. Like if I have 4 outliers in the column(data), it gives 6 outliers. on the execution of the code for one of the  columns I have as input feature, I get 3 outliers instead of 2.

Comment: Get rid of all the backticks, and fix your indentation.

Comment: Show how you're setting `B5`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `outliers` inside the function. Otherwise, every time you call `detect_outliers()` you append to the results from the previous call.